# EF Core Key is already being tracked

Tags: c#, ef-core-3.1

An error occurs while using EF Core 3.1.6

I also tried Detach on Entity but the error was not fixed
Is it impossible to reuse the tracked key?

```
The instance of entity type 'Data' cannot be tracked because another instance with the key value '{Id : 1657126}' is already being tracked. When attaching e
xisting entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached.
```

**Proc.cs**

```cs
public async Task ProcData(IReadOnlyCollection<DataObject> datas) {
  var ctx = new DbContext();
  var transaction = await ctx.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();

  for(var i = 0; i < datas.Count; i++) {
    var data = datas.ElementAt(i);
    var g_Data =
          await ctx.Data.SingleOrDefaultAsync(o =>
            o.Id== o.Id) ??
          new Data{Id = data.Id};
    ctx.AddOrUpdate(g_Data); // Error
  }
  await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();

  await Process(ctx);
  try
  {
    await transaction.CommitAsync();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    await transaction.RollBackAsync();
  }
}

private async Task Process(DbContext ctx) {
  // something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two entities with the same ID (Primary Key) tracked and inserted in DB.

In the first case you are comparing Id of Data with itself which is useless and this is the source of error.

Try changing

```
var g_Data = await ctx.Data.SingleOrDefaultAsync(o => o.Id == o.Id) ?? new Data{Id = data.Id};
```

To

```
var g_Data = await ctx.Data.SingleOrDefaultAsync(o => o.Id == data.Id) ?? new Data{Id = data.Id};
```

***EDIT:***

There is a nice way to improve you code by adding foreach loop.

```
public async Task ProcData(IReadOnlyCollection<DataObject> datas) {
  var ctx = new DbContext();
  var transaction = await ctx.Database.BeginTransactionAsync();
  foreach(var data in datas)
  {
    var g_Data = await ctx.Data.SignleOrDefault(o => o.Id = data.Id) ?? new Data{Id == data.Id}
    ctx.AddOrUpdate(g_Data)
  }
  await ctx.SaveChangesAsync();

  await Process(ctx);
  try
  {
    await transaction.CommitAsync();
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    await transaction.RollBackAsync();
  }
}

private async Task Process(DbContext ctx) {
  // something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are all types of problems with this code but regarding the one your question is about - it appears that you already have fetched a range of entities, then you iterate through them and fetch them one by one *again* and do it incorrectly (as Neistow already pointed out). Whether or not the second fetch is done without tracking/is detached, once you `.AddOrUpdate()` your entity, EF will attempt to start tracking it and will fail since you already have another instance tracked with the same key.

There are many valid approaches here. You could:

1. Reuse your fetched entities.
   It's not clear from the code you provide, but I assume `DataObject` is a data transfer object type and `Data` is your entity type. You could reuse your entities directly. However, it's tough for me to say exactly how that would look, since you attempt to do insertion and update here at once and the only way you differentiate between new and existing entities is by re-fetching them from database (which is the cause of your issue). Ideally you should already know which of your DTOs are new, `AddRange()` your new `Data` entities based on just them and then `SaveChangesAsync()`. Since EF tracks your existing entities, they will get updated even without explicitly calling for update.
2. Use `FindAsync()` - unlike `SingleOrDefaultAsync()` it checks your local/tracked entities and fetches them from EF cache instead of going directly to your database.

```
var g_Data = await ctx
    .Data
    .FindAsync(d => d.Id == data.Id);
```

3. Not track the original collection. You don't provide the code here that performs the first fetch, but if it would look something like this:

```
var dataObjects = await ctx
    .Data
    .AsNoTracking() // <<-- Do not track the entities you fetch.
    .Where(do => myPredicate)
    .ToListAsync()
    // Transform to DTOs.
```

your initial entity range wouldn't be tracked, so there would be no key conflicts later on your re-fetch.